# Django-Chart Circular request error

Tags: python, json, django

I'm trying to render a page using django-chartit by using models and examples provided by the Django-Chartit docs.

My model looks like this.

```
class MonthlySchedule(models.Model):
     ''' Monthly schedule for django-chartit statistics''' 
    months = (
        (u'jan',_('January')),
        (u'feb',_('February')),
        (u'mar',_('March')),
        (u'apr',_('April')),
        (u'may',_('May')),
        (u'jun',_('June')),
        (u'jul',_('July')),
        (u'aug',_('August')),
        (u'sep',_('September')),
        (u'oct',_('October')),
        (u'nov',_('November')),
        (u'dec',_('December'))
        )

     programme = models.ForeignKey(Redaktion, related_name='red_monthly', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     year = models.CharField(_('Year'), max_length=4, blank=False, default=year)
     month = models.CharField(_('Month'), choices=months, max_length=3)
     current_size = models.DecimalField(_('Current size(TB)'), max_digits=4, decimal_places=1, blank=True, null=True)
     target_size = models.DecimalField(_('Target size(TB)'), max_digits=4, decimal_places=1, blank=True, null=True)

     def __str__(self):
        return ''
     class Meta:
         verbose_name = (_("quota"))
         verbose_name_plural = (_("quotas"))
```

and my views look like this...

```
@staff_member_required
def ChartitSchedule(request, red=None):
    '''Monthly disk Quotas'''
    ds = DataPool(
        series=[{
            'options': {
            'source': MonthlySchedule.objects.filter(programme__pk=red)
        },
        'terms': [
            'month',
            {'Current Size': 'current_size'},
            'target_size'
        ]
    }]
    )

    cht = Chart(
        datasource=ds,
        series_options=[{
            'options': {
            'type': 'line',
            'stacking': False
        },
        'terms': {
            'month': [
                'target_size',
                'Current Size'
            ]
        }
    }],
        chart_options={
            'title': {
            'text': 'Disk Quotas'
        },
        'xAxis': {
            'title': {
                'text': 'Month'
            }
        }
    })
    return render(request, 'sysadmin/chartit.html', {'this_chart': True, 'these_quotas':cht})
```

and my template looks like this....

```
{% extends 'base2.html' %}
{% block title %}Programme Quotas{% endblock %}
{% load static %}


{% block add_to_header %}
{% load chartit %}
{{ these_quotas|load_charts:"container" }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<!-- CHART-IT -->
     {% if this_chart %}
      <div id="pagetitle">Disk Quotas {{ red }}</div>
      <div id="content"><!-- CONTENT -->
       <div id='container'></div>
      </div><!-- CONTENT -->
     {% endif%}

{% endblock content %}
```

This is pretty much the same as the examples in the docs, except that I am using choices for the months (which is a bad idea I think as they sort alphabetic).

The view returns the two chartit objects and the json looks like it's ok.

The error I get is a 'Circular reference detected' Exception Location:  c:\python35\Lib\json\encoder.py in iterencode, line 256

Which is pretty much out of my hands I think - or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry - for answering my own question, but I think that it is important for anyone else trying to use django-chartit to find an answer to this question.

Following the docs exactly, I get it to work. Chartit won't accept the month values from the choices in the model - it might be documented, and to be honest I haven't read the entire documentation.

There is a fix in the second example for the month names, by fixing them in the view, but if you try to do it in the model so that you can get a nice admin form with month names - it will fail with a circular error.